# Get DisplayName of domain users who are members of local groups

Tags: powershell, script

I have a script which lists all local groups and their members and give CSV output.

I modified script to get displayName property of domain user members of local groups (Not domain groups not local groups and not local users. Just the displayName of domain users)

But the script does not work stable. It shows the same displayname for every member without checking if it is a domain object or local object. Or without checking if it is a group or user.

Is there any suggestion to achieve my goal?

```
$complist = get-content C:\temp\comps2.txt
foreach ($comp in $complist){

$strComputer = $comp #Enter the name of the target computer, localhost is used by default
Write-Host "Computer: $strComputer"
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$strComputer"
$objCount = ($computer.psbase.children | measure-object).count
Write-Host "Q-ty objects for computer '$strComputer' = $objCount"
$Counter = 1
$result = @()
foreach($adsiObj in $computer.psbase.children)
{
switch -regex($adsiObj.psbase.SchemaClassName)
  {
    "group"
    {
      $group = $adsiObj.name
      $LocalGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$strComputer/$group,group"
      $Members = @($LocalGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
      $objCount = ($Members | measure-object).count
      Write-Host "Q-ty objects for group '$group' = $objCount"
      $GName = $group.tostring()

      ForEach ($Member In $Members) {

      
        $Name = $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null)
        $Path = $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("ADsPath", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null)
        $membername= Get-ADUser $name -Properties displayname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty displayname
        
        Write-Host " Object = $Path"

                 $isGroup = ($Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Class", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null) -eq "group")

                


        If (($Path -like "*/$strComputer/*") -Or ($Path -like "WinNT://NT*")) { $Type = "Local"
        } Else 
        
        {$Type = "Domain"}

        

        

        $result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          Computername = $strComputer
          NameMember = $Name
          PathMember = $Path
          TypeMemeber = $Type
          ParentGroup = $GName
          isGroupMemeber = $isGroup
          Depth = $Counter
          Membername = $membername

        }
      }
    }
  } #end switch
  
} #end foreach

Write-Host "Total objects = " ($result | measure-object).count
$result = $result | select-object Computername, ParentGroup, NameMember, TypeMemeber, PathMember, isGroupMemeber, membername
$result | Export-Csv -append -path ("C:\temp\LocalGroups({0})-{1:yyyyMMddHHmm}.csv" -f
$env:COMPUTERNAME,(Get-Date)) -Delimiter ";" -Encoding "UTF8" -force -NoTypeInformation}
```

Comment: "It shows the same DisplayName for every member without checking if it is a domain object or local object. " - You will have to make that check yourself by using an conditional statement.  However, it's confusing that you are using [Get-ADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps) against a user that only exist on the local machine.  I am shocked the command you are running returns anything of value since DisplayName isn't a property of a user according to the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: This may help... 
$lgroups = Get-LocalGroup;
    foreach ($l in ($lgroups)) {Write-host "LocalGroup:$l";write-host "members:"(get-localgroupmember $l)}

Answer (score 0):

COuld I suggest another approach :

1. Use Get-LocalGroup cmdlet to query all Local groups (foreach loop)
2. Use Get-LocalGroupMember to query members of the current group

You could filter on the content

```
(Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $Group.Name).Name | Select-String -Pattern "MyDomain\*"
```

and put the result in a `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: have you looked at the `.PrincipalSource` & `.ObjectClass` properties of the objects you get from `Get-LocalGroupMember`?